# Is redirection to user from 3rd party web app to salesforce dashboard is possible and how?

Tags: authentication, remote-access

I created a login form at my domain xyz.com, now user enters salesforce username and password on form residing at my xyz.com, if credentials correct redirect user to salesforce dashboard otherwise flag error message.

FYI - I am following this tut but not sure if I am on correct page

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_authenticate.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have users entering username and password directly into your website.  You need to delegate authentication to Salesforce.

The easiest way to do this is simply linking to the dashboard -- users will be  stopped (temporarily) by the Salesforce login page.  After they log in successfully, they will go to the dashboard.